# Access on prem AD in a network from Azure App Service

Tags: active-directory, azure-web-app-service

How can I update on-prem AD (create/update/delete objects) in a network from my Azure App Service or ASE? I found that Hybrid connections do not support AD because App Service cannot be domain joined. What else can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have said, [Hybrid Connections not support Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections), because you cannot domain join an App Service worker and hence Windows Authentication will not work. You are unlikely to get around this, especially if you are hosting your app as a web app.

Workaround(not with app service):

1.Use Azure AD to create an Active Directory domain in the cloud and connect it to your on-premises Active Directory domain. Azure AD Connect integrates your on-premises directories with Azure AD.

2.Extend your existing on-premises Active Directory infrastructure to Azure, by deploying a VM in Azure that runs AD DS as a domain controller.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/).

Comment: Thanks Joey! Seems like we will be having an ExpressRoute to connect to on-prem resources in the client network.